# Fast way to sum Fourier series?

Tags: optimization, signal-processing, fft, fftw

I have generated the coefficients using FFTW, now I want to reconstruct the original data, but using only the first `numCoefs` coefficients rather than all of them. At the moment I'm using the below code, which is very slow:

```
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i )
{
    double sum = 0;
    for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < numCoefs; ++j )
    {
        sum += ( coefs[j][0] * cos( j * omega * i ) ) + ( coefs[j][1] * sin( j * omega * i ) );
    }
    data[i] = sum;
}
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Just zero the unwanted coefficients and do an IFFT with FFTW - it will be a lot more efficient than doing an IDFT as above.

Comment: @Paul R: You're right, I didn't realize the code was doing an inverse FFT.

Comment: Silly me, I already tried deleting the coefficients, which leads to many errors. I should have just set them to 0. If you make this an answer I'll give you the tick. Thanks to all those who replied.

Comment: OK - have added this as an answer, plus a cautionary note re frequency domain filtering and window functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A much simpler solution would be to zero the unwanted coefficients and then do an IFFT with FFTW. This will be a lot more efficient than doing an IDFT as above.

*Note that you may get some artefacts in the time domain when you do this kind of thing - you're effectively multiplying by a step function in the frequency domain, which is equivalent to convolution with a sinc function in the time domain. To reduce the resulting "ringing" in the time domain you should use a window function to smooth out the transition between non-zero and zero coeffs.*

Answer (score 1):

If your `numCoefs` is anywhere near or greater than log(length), then an IFFT, which is O(n*log(n)) in computational complexity, will most likely be faster, as well as pre-optimized for you.  Just zero all the bins except for the coefficients you want to keep, and make sure to also keep their negative frequency complex conjugates as well if you want a real result.

If your `numCoefs` is small relative to log(length), then other optimizations you could try include using `sinf()` and `cosf()` if you don't really need more than 6 digits of precision, and pre-calculating omega*i outside the inner loop (although your compiler should do be doing that for you unless you have the optimization setting low or off).